# Use CloudFormer in Round-Trip Engineering of AWS Resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, continuous-integration, aws-cloudformation

I would like to use CloudFormer in an automated way to generate templates of existing resources in my VPC.  I can create the cloudformer instance using Ruby SDK CloudFormation::Client.create_stack() and tear it down using  CloudFormation::Client.delete_stack() - but while it's running, I can't figure out how to talk to it to ask it to generate cloudformation templates for resources.  I envision doing something like:

```
for every SecurityGroup in VPC:
    ask CloudFormer to generate a cloudformation template of the SecurityGroup
    store the template in S3
    scan the template for compliance with business rules etc.
end
```

How do I talk to CloudFormer once it's running (in a non-interactive way)?  Has anyone done this?  I hope I don't have to use Selenium etc. to talk to it's webUI.

Answer (score 3):

CloudFormer is still in beta phase and does not have command-line-interface tools in the same way that other *first-class* AWS services do, so, unfortunately, there is no way to interact with the running application programmatically.