# Which AWS services does AWS CloudFormer support?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito

AWS CloudFormation offers a default stack named CloudFormer, a template creation tool. CloudFormer creates a CloudFormation template from your current AWS environment, allowing you to click which manually created resources to include in your template.

The [AWS CloudFormer documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html) does not list the AWS services that CloudFormer supports. There is an announcement from 2013 ([CloudFormer Now Supports Amazon VPC and More AWS Resources](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/06/06/cloudformer-now-supports-amazon-vpc-and-more-aws-resources/)) that lists a subset of supported services, but there is no complete list.

Which services does AWS CloudFormer support? For example, does it support commonly used severless managed services, such as AWS Lambda and AWS Cognito?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Sadly CloudFormer is deprecated and **no longer maintained** by AWS.

> CloudFormer is actually a very old tool that is not maintained. It has been in "beta" for many years.

[John Rotenstein Developer Advocate at Amazon Web Services May 26 '20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62010567/export-existing-ec2-instance-to-cloudformation-json-yaml/62013052#62013052)

Thus CloudFormer is not recommended for use as its not reliable.

You can have a look at a third party tool called [Former2](https://former2.com/) which seems to be much more useful and reliable than the `CloudFormer`:

> Former2 allows you to **generate Infrastructure-as-Code outputs** from your existing resources within your AWS account. By making the relevant calls using the AWS JavaScript SDK, Former2 will scan across your infrastructure and present you with the list of resources for you to choose which to generate outputs for.

Comment: In my hands, Former2 worked well with AWS Cognito. The only hiccup was that Former2 added unnecessary param fields for default openid attributes (emails, address). Cognito creates these attributes automatically. Resolved by simply deleting the default params from the Former2 output.

Comment: Is there an official end of life announcement for CloudFormer anywhere? I definitely believe you (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66239897/123671) but can't find anything from AWS saying that CloudFormer is officially not longer supported.

Comment: @mikemaccana It was from AWS emploee on SO, would have to dig through comments and answers to find it. But these days, AWS is advertising Former2 on their blog anyway, explaining how it is used in places of CloudFormer. [Example blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/accelerate-infrastructure-as-code-development-with-open-source-former2/). They reffer to CloudFormer as "the previous CloudFormer tool".

Comment: Thanks Marcin! I also found https://stackoverflow.com/a/62943708/123671 (a deleted answer to this question ) which contains an post from another AWS employee stating CloudFormer is dead and to use Former2.

Comment: @mikemaccana Found the comment. It is the first comment in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62010567/export-existing-ec2-instance-to-cloudformation-json-yaml/62013052#62013052) answer.

Comment: @mikemaccana So there are two references:-)

Answer (score 4):

AWS CloudFormer is not a complete solution for creating CloudFormation templates from your existing AWS infrastructure.

AWS CloudFormer supports a very limited subset of AWS resources, focused on Network, Compute and Storage. The vast majority of AWS managed services, such as AWS Lambda and AWS Cognito are not support.
[image]

If you'd like to create a template of your network infrastructure (VPCs et al.) and EC2 instances, CloudFormer may be useful. If you're using other AWS managed services, you're out of luck.

Additionally, CloudFormer [does not have a programmatic interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52723319/3684641).

**AWS CloudFormer's core support**
DNS: Route53
Network: VPC, Subnets
EC2: Instances, LoadBalancer, Autoscaling, ElasticIP, SecurityGroups
Storage: S3, EBS, RDS, SimpleDB, DynamoDB, ElastiCache, Redshift

**Other supported services**

- CloudWatch Alarms (but not CloudWatch dashboards)
- CloudFront
- Elastic Beanstalk
- Kinesis Streams
- OpsWorks
- SNS
- SQS

**Common services that are NOT supported by AWS CloudFormer**

- Cognito
- ECS
- EFS
- EKS
- Glue
- Lambda
- [SageMaker](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/hsh0bt/limitations_of_cloudformations_cloudformer_unable/)