# AWS Cloud Formation. Create Stack from account architecture

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

My question is simple. Is there a way to import my current architecture in the system account I'm using in my AWS account as it's own stack?

What I mean is ... My account has a dozen Lambda functions, S3 buckets, databases and such. This is all
deeply integrated. Is there a way to automatically have a CloudFormation stack created? this using my existing resources as a blueprint instead of me manually re-creating everything in CloudFormation myself?

I would call this an Anti-Stack, excuse the pun. But in all seriousness, this is basically the reverse
of a stack. Creating a stack from my architecture, instead of creating architecture from a stack.

Comment: Are you looking for some thing already mentioned in [this existing thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65739411/14843902)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is **no full out-of-the box solution** for that. As far as AWS is concerned, you would have to [import resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-existing-stack.html) into CloudFormation. This requires you to prepare all the templates yourself with match your current architecture. This can be quite troublesome and time-consuming task, but its doable.

AWS used to develop [CloudFormer](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/building-aws-cloudformation-templates-using-cloudformer/) tool which simplifies this process, but the tool is **no longer maintained** by AWS.

Instead, there is a **third party**, open-source tool called [former2](https://former2.com/) which can help you in generation of templates from your existing infrastructure. The former2 is used by corporate clients of AWS as explained in the [AWS blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/accelerate-infrastructure-as-code-development-with-open-source-former2/).

Comment: Perfect, Thank you!