# replicate existing AWS resource with CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I have AWS resources that I manually created in the browser

Now I want to have the ability to create equivalent resources using CloudFormation. Is there a tool that turns an already existing AWS resource into a cloudformation template that would create it with all its current properties?

As an example, I have an IAM role with many attached policies. I would like to have a fully functional CloudFormation Template that replicates it.

Is this possible?

The alternative is going through the CloudFormation IAM Role documentation and see all options and manually inspect these properties on the console and replicate them with trial and error.

I have tried to create a stack in CloudFormation using existing resources but it asks for a template... I don't have a template I want to create one.. I also tried to create a stack using the Designer but I couldnt find an option to import existing resources there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AWS does not provide an abstracted way to do this. They used to offer CloudFormer, an extension of CloudFormation(CFN) that would create templates from existing resources in an AWS account, however the service was [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62944334/9970488) per another stack overflow question. [AWS does offer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html) the ability to bring manually created resources into a CFN template or stack through the `resource import` method, which would enable you to then have them managed by CFN. To automatically create a CFN template or stack from existing manually created AWS resources it appears your only option is a 3rd party tool called [Former2](https://former2.com/).